# Cannot convert value of type - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to learn Swift by migrating an existing Objective-C project, but have some issues with one of the methods.

I get the following error: "Cannot convert value of type '(SBStop, UInt, _) -> Void' to expected argument type '(AnyObject, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer) -> Void'"

Any suggestion on how I can get this working?

Swift:

```
stops.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(stopItem: SBStop, idx: UInt, stop) -> Void in
            stopLocation = CLLocation(latitude: stopItem.latitude, longitude: stopItem.longitude)
            stopItem.distance = stopLocation.distanceFromLocation(location)
        })
```

Working Objective-C code:

```
    [stops enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SBStop *stopItem, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        stopLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:stopItem.latitude longitude:stopItem.longitude];
        stopItem.distance = [stopLocation distanceFromLocation:location];         // in meters
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using the incorrect type annotations in your completion closure. This should do:

```
   stops.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(stopItem, _ , _) in
               guard let stopItem = stopItem as? SBStop else { return }
               stopLocation = CLLocation(latitude: stopItem.latitude, longitude: stopItem.longitude)
               stopItem.distance = stopLocation.distanceFromLocation(location)
           })
```

Explanation:
The library that you're using defines the parameters of the completion block as `(AnyObject, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer)`. If you're expecting the AnyObject to be of a specific type, you'll need to cast it appropriately (in this case using `guard let`)

The `_` is a Swift-ism that indicates an unused parameter.

The `-> Void` is implied for closures unless otherwise specified, so it's not explicitly needed here.

Comment: Perfect, rudd! That solved my issue! And thanks for the explanation, I really appreciate it!